# Mysql - complicated query giving me issues

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a really hard time with this query.  So the idea of this is that every year, faculty_id gets populated with a rank and step value.  Depending on what happened over the course of the year, the rank and step may or may not change and they are independent of each other.  The Step may change but the rank could stay the same for example, or vise versa

```
+--------------------------+--------------+
| Field                    | Type         |
+--------------------------+--------------+
| id                       | int(11)      |
| year                     | smallint(6)  |
| faculty_id               | int(11)      |
| rank_id                  | smallint(6)  |
| step_code                | varchar(4)   |
+--------------------------+--------------+
```

Now the query I have been banging my head against a brick wall over for the past few hours is this:

I need to be able to pick a `year` for a particular `faculty_id`.  I then need to look at the current `rank` and `step` value for that year and output for how many years they have been stuck at that current rank and step value.

For example

```
+---------------------------------------
| id | year | faculty_id | rank | step |
----------------------------------------
| 1  | 2005 |    1       |  1   |  I   |
| 2  | 2006 |    1       |  2   |  II  |
| 3  | 2007 |    1       |  3   |  III |
| 4  | 2008 |    1       |  3   |  III |
| 5  | 2009 |    1       |  3   |  IV  |
| 6  | 2007 |    2       |  5   |  III |
| 7  | 2008 |    2       |  5   |  III |
| 8  | 2009 |    2       |  6   |  III |
----------------------------------------
Year = 2009
+-----------------------------------------------
| faculty_id | rank | step | rank yr | step yr |
------------------------------------------------
|    1       | 3    |  IV  |   3     |    1    |
|    2       | 6    |  III |   1     |    3    |
------------------------------------------------

Year = 2008
+-----------------------------------------------
| faculty_id | rank | step | rank yr | step yr |
------------------------------------------------
|    1       | 3    | III  |   2     |    2    |
|    2       | 5    | III  |   2     |    2    |
------------------------------------------------
```

Doing this programtically is not an option given the circumstances, reports need to be pulled but the source code is currently unavailable.  I am getting nowhere trying to do this myself, this is beyond my knowledge level of SQL.  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: 
Just to clarify, I am looking for continuity in the years when looking at how long a person has been at the rank and step.  If they are

Rank 1 for a years

Rank 3 for a year

Back to Rank 1 for 2 more years.

When I run a query for the current year for example...I only see Rank 1 @ 2 years at rank.  There was a break in the middle where this person was Rank 3, so the initial year at Rank 1 doesn't count for this query.

Comment: Can you recheck expected results for year 2009? They seem to be inconsintent with your explanation.

Comment: agreed in 2009 faculty_id 2 would have only been that combination of rank and step for the 1 year, in the previous years they were only rank 5.

Comment: Yes your right, I was copying and pasting trying to make up data and made a mistake.  its fixed now.

Comment: Not sure if my last edit helped or not, could you please take a look and if it works accept the answer? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

With the given example the following would do:

```
select faculty_id, rank, step, count(id) as years
from table 
group by faculty_id, rank, step
```

As your 'rank yr' and 'step yr' looks should always have same value to me.
However this query would not really show you how many years they have been stuck in a rank, say if 2005 they are at rank 5, and then next two years they are rank 6, but again downgraded to rank 5, the query would count those years as two years on rank 5, but they are not continuously. If you need something like that it could be something more complex.

**EDIT:**

OK I know this looks stupid and not that nice but it should solve the problem for you and cover 10 years continues same rank and step:

```
select QueryYear.faculty_id, QueryYear.rank, QueryYear.step,
    Case When Tminus9.faculty_id IS NOT NULL THEN 10
    ELSE Case When Tminus8.faculty_id IS NOT NULL THEN 9
    ELSE Case When Tminus7.faculty_id IS NOT NULL THEN 8
    ELSE Case When Tminus6.faculty_id IS NOT NULL THEN 7
    ELSE Case When Tminus5.faculty_id IS NOT NULL THEN 6
    ELSE Case When Tminus4.faculty_id IS NOT NULL THEN 5
    ELSE Case When Tminus3.faculty_id IS NOT NULL THEN 4
    ELSE Case When Tminus2.faculty_id IS NOT NULL THEN 3
    ELSE Case When Tminus1.faculty_id IS NOT NULL THEN 2
    ELSE 1 END
from table QueryYear
    left join table Tminus1 on Tminus1.faculty_id = QueryYear.faculty_id and QueryYear.rank = Tminus1.rank and QueryYear.step = Tminus1.step and QueryYear.year = Tminus1.year + 1
    left join table Tminus2 on Tminus2.faculty_id = QueryYear.faculty_id and QueryYear.rank = Tminus2.rank and QueryYear.step = Tminus2.step and QueryYear.year = Tminus2.year + 2
    left join table Tminus3 on Tminus3.faculty_id = QueryYear.faculty_id and QueryYear.rank = Tminus3.rank and QueryYear.step = Tminus3.step and QueryYear.year = Tminus3.year + 3
    left join table Tminus4 on Tminus4.faculty_id = QueryYear.faculty_id and QueryYear.rank = Tminus4.rank and QueryYear.step = Tminus4.step and QueryYear.year = Tminus4.year + 4
    left join table Tminus5 on Tminus5.faculty_id = QueryYear.faculty_id and QueryYear.rank = Tminus5.rank and QueryYear.step = Tminus5.step and QueryYear.year = Tminus5.year + 5
    left join table Tminus6 on Tminus6.faculty_id = QueryYear.faculty_id and QueryYear.rank = Tminus6.rank and QueryYear.step = Tminus6.step and QueryYear.year = Tminus6.year + 6
    left join table Tminus7 on Tminus7.faculty_id = QueryYear.faculty_id and QueryYear.rank = Tminus7.rank and QueryYear.step = Tminus7.step and QueryYear.year = Tminus7.year + 7
    left join table Tminus8 on Tminus8.faculty_id = QueryYear.faculty_id and QueryYear.rank = Tminus8.rank and QueryYear.step = Tminus8.step and QueryYear.year = Tminus8.year + 8
    left join table Tminus9 on Tminus9.faculty_id = QueryYear.faculty_id and QueryYear.rank = Tminus9.rank and QueryYear.step = Tminus9.step and QueryYear.year = Tminus9.year + 9
where QueryYear.year = 2009
group by faculty_id, rank, step
```

By given a where condition on the QueryYear table, it would not have any other year data, and then next table it left join would have a previous year data if it was actually share the same rank and step. And it this second table by left join still has value it means it is at least 2 continues year, and so on and so on. So when the result is 10 it actually means 10+.

There might be a better solution but this one would work.

Comment: The rank and step years could be the same in some scenarios but its not guaranteed and in most cases they are very different.  The issues you mentioned that your query does not account for are the exact items I am trying to accomplish...this is complex.  I need the continuous years at that particular rank and step, if at any point those values change then the counter stops.

Comment: so if say same rank showed in two continues years and then they upgraded, but later downgraded to old rank for another two years, should the result show 2 record with same rank and same rank year twice or just one? I think you need to be more specific about the requirement otherwise we can't help that much

Comment: Only 1 record per faculty_id is to be shown and the Rank is 2 years as per the current streak.  The previous 2 years of that same rank don't matter anymore because it changed in the middle.  As mentioned, its continuous years at that same rank.  Having a rank change in the middle doesn't make it continuous anymore.

Comment: If only 1 record per faculty_id, does that means you only need the latest record? is it possible we just use some max function to get a join with it?

Comment: The requirements state that the year is an input, so the "latest" record can be the given year.  If the input year is 2008, I don't care about 2009 or above.  So 2008 would be considered the latest record in this result set.  The `rank` and `step` values for 2008 would be the one we are looking at to calculate the `rank year` and `step year` values.